# Face-covering and fitnah

Tags: hijab

So, I know there is debate about whether Muslim women should cover their faces. From my research:

- In the Hanbali madhhab, the dominant opinion is that **covering the face is obligatory** in the presence of non-mahram men, as the face is considered part of a woman's awrah.
- **The other three schools**: The Hanafi, Maliki, and Shafi'i madhhabs do not generally regard the face as awrah, and so they **don't consider it obligatory to cover the face**. However, scholars typically say **that if uncovering the face leads to fitnah, then it becomes [obligatory to cover it.](https://islamqa.org/hanafi/daruliftaa-birmingham/19997/niqab/)**

My question is: What does fear of fitnah mean? Who decided whether uncovering the face leads to fitnah? Does that mean if a woman thinks men might be attracted to her, she should cover her face? or is this expected in certain environments?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, fear of fitnah could mean any (or a combination) of the following:

1. **High risk of attraction**: If a woman's face is likely to attract attention that may lead to temptation, scholars advise covering it; as noted by Ibn Abidin Shami:

> A young woman is prevented from exposing her face, not because it is
> part of the awrah, rather for the fear of temptation.” (Raddul Muhtar
> P.532 V.9)

**2. Prevailing immorality:** In a society where immorality is rampant, and the likelihood of haraam thoughts or actions is high, covering the face is advised.

**3. The role of social norm (urf)**: In some societies, the majority of Muslim women wear niqab (or other types of face-covering) and uncovering the face is seen as a deviation from the norm. In such situations, a woman should cover her face to avoid unnecessary attention and social disturbance. The principle here is to maintain social harmony and prevent discord, which is also a type of fitnah.